# Android Fragment Class Cannot Inflate Resource

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am designing an Android app that uses fragments. I have never used these before, but they seemed like a useful solution to my needs. When I tried to generate a blank fragment with the Android Studio function under `File`, the subclass of `Fragment` called `DietaryRestrictions` that was created gave an error in the `onCreateView` method. The error is: `Cannot resolve symbol 'fragment_dietary_restrictions'`

Here is my `Fragment` class:

```
    public class DietaryRestrictions extends Fragment {

    public DietaryRestrictions() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dietary_restrictions, container, false);
    }
}
```

And here is my Android Studio-generated resource file for the `Fragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.DietaryRestrictions">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The resource definitely exists in the project, so I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly as I've followed instructions from various sources like
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-tab-layout-in-android-app and documentation located at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating

Any help would be appreciated and I can provide additional code snippets if needed.

SOLUTION
So, I am unsure if this is an issue with Android Studio or not, but I closed the program and reopened later, and the fragment was able to be found in the layout inflater! I hope this can help if any other developers are seeing this issue with using fragments, as it appears this only happened when I used fragments.

Comment: Does it actually say `Cannot resolve symbol 'fragment.dietary_restrictions'` and not, say, `Cannot resolve symbol 'fragment_dietary_restrictions'`?

Comment: @RyanMentley My apologies, this was a typo on my part. I have since edited the question. The error does say the latter

Comment: Where is your fragment_dietary_restrictions.xml file located in your project?

Comment: @Tiko it is located under the res/layout folder